# Enhanced Ecommerce Product Price, Shipping and TAX

Tags: enhanced-ecommerce

I don't understand which value of product price and value of tax is right.

1. I have product

   ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
     'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
     'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
     'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
     'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
     'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
     'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).

   *=> Product price without tax????*

   'coupon': 'APPARELSALE',          // Product coupon (string).
     'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
   });

Q.: The Product price is price with tax or not?

2. I have shipping (1.48 without tax and 1.8 with tax)

   ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
   'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
     'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
     'revenue': '33.85',                     // Revenue (currency).
     'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).

   *=> Tax is total tax of products tax and shipping tax (or payment tax if I have) or not?*

   'shipping': '1.8',                     // Shipping (currency).

   *=> Shipping price is price with tax or not?*

   'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
   });

Q.: Tax is total tax of products tax and shipping tax (or payment tax if I have) or not?
Q.: Shipping price is price with tax or not?

Thanks

Rudolf

Answer (score 0):

the numbers in the documentation (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/enhanced-ecommerce#transaction) suggest that the 'ec:addProduct' items are net. The revenue in the purchase action seems to include tax and shipping.

It's unclear if the shipping is net (but if it's consistent, it's net and shipping tax is included in the total tax).

Also unclear if the 'ec:addProduct' item prices are per item or total given the quantity. But most likely it is the total (qty 2, item price 10$ => price in tracking is 20$).

I get a sense that GA leaves it to the company using the tracking to choose what counts as revenue - but hell, a recommendation would be nice so 3rd party vendors have some commonly agreed upon practice.